# SVG: How to position my textpaths inside my SVG?

Tags: css, html, svg

Consider the [following fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Qcaa8/). (Open it in firefox) How can I position my textpath inside my SVG so that it doesn't gets hidden?

I tried adding `x` and `y` attributes to both `svg` tag and the `text` tag but the text doesn't moves.

```
<svg width="597" height="98" style="overflow:visible; ">
<defs>
    <path d=" M 0,0  L 596,0  M 0,96  L 596,96 " id="_x0000_i1042tp" />
</defs>
<text x="10" y="40" style="font-size:48px; font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;; fill:#369; " method="stretch">
    <textPath xlink:href="#_x0000_i1042tp" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">WortArt Test3</textPath>
</text>
```

Also the above fiddle doesn't shows anything in Chrome (or any other webkit based browsers), the issue is that webkit based browsers hide overflowing SVG. How can I fix that?

Thanx in advance!!

Comment: why the negative markings and the close votes? It is a problem related to html/svg...

Comment: Not sure why neg markings, but maybe its worth showing the code also in the question.

Comment: @Ian ok i will if that helps but I added a fiddle for that so that everyone can not only see my SVG but also see what it produces..

Comment: Yep, its just that jsfiddle may not always be around, so people like questions that are self contained. There may be other reasons, not sure!

Comment: Why do people insist on calling Firefox "Mozilla"? We don't call IE "Microsoft" or Chrome "Google". (Or do you actually mean the defunct [Mozilla Suite](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/products/mozilla1.x/)?

Comment: @Quentin hahaha... no i meant firefox. I will change it in my question, thanx for correcting me.

Comment: add the following to the svg element to get it to show in webkit : `viewBox="0 0 597 98"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to mess around with the baseline and alignment attributes. The following seems to get it inside the two lines, but not along the top of the second line:

```
<textPath dominant-baseline="hanging" xlink:href="#mypath">WortArt Test3</textPath>
```

Here is the full fiddle, which works in Chrome:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/Qcaa8/1/

Comment: Because it was broken otherwise. Not sure why, probably due to the framing in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Change `0,0  L 596,0` to `0,X  L 596,X` where `X` is the position of the *bottom* of the text. (So if you want it to be at the top of the image, you should use (aprox) the font size of the text).

Comment: I don't think I can proceed by changing the path itself since it is programatically generated and I don't want to mess with that code of mine. Can't we reposition my text by adding some position attributes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dy` on the <text> element to move the text down, or you can adjust the path so that it describes the text baseline that you really want. See [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Qcaa8/2/).

The `overflow:visible` not having any effect in Chrome, that's filed as [bug 231577](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=231577). Note that webkit/Safari has the [same bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=96163) too.